# can't install rstan because depending on itself

Tags: r, shiny, rstan

i'm trying to install Rstan on Debian for Rstudio server and seems to be a dead end.

The issue is:

- I'm installing a package that depends on rstan. So I try to install rstan before

  install.package("rstan")
- **Error:** rstan depend on brms, so I try to install brms

  install.package("brms")
- **Error:** brms depends on shinystan, so I try to install shinystan

  install.package("shinystan")
- **Error:** shinystan depends on rstan (WTF!!!!)

and this is the dead end.

How can I get out this circle?

Comment: The rstan package does not depend in any way on the brms package. What are your actual error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. `brms` isn't listed in the `depends` or `imports` of `rstan`. Indeed, `brms` imports `rstan`.

Regardless, you could try installing them all at once.

`install.packages(c("rstan", "brms", "shinystan"))`

However, the default values for parameter `dependencies` should install all "Depends", "Imports", and "LinkingTo" packages. Are you specifying a value for `repos`? The default is `getOption("repos")`, but if this is returning `NULL` then the `dependencies` parameter is not used. Try specifying `repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org"`.